# A sessão não está sendo atualizada

Tags: php, session

A *session* não quer aceitar valor do método `POST`. Ela salva a primeira vez, mas depois que a página é atualizada ela some.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['b'])){   
    if ($_SESSION['b'] !=""){

        $_POST['email'] =$_SESSION['b'];

        echo $_SESSION['b']."<br/>1";
        }else{

            $_SESSION['b'] = $_POST['email'];
            echo$_SESSION['b']."<br/>2";
        }
}
else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['b'] = "";
}?>
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
Email: <input type="email" name="email" class="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" class="enviar" value="Encurtar" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['b'])){   
    if ($_SESSION['b'] !=""){

        $_POST['email'] =$_SESSION['b'];

        echo $_SESSION['b']."<br/>1";
        }else{

            $_SESSION['b'] = $_POST['email'];
            echo$_SESSION['b']."<br/>2";
        }
}
else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['b'] = "";
}?>
```

Comment: Quando entra no primeiro If, a Session não está startada

Comment: colouei mas messmo assim n funcionou

Comment: Pq vc atribui o valor da session ao post?  $_post['email'] = $_session['b']

Comment: **Remova todos** os `session_start();` e adicione `session_start();` **somente uma vez** na segunda linha do seu código (logo após o primeiro `<?php`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para uso de sessões, você deve chamar a função **session_start()** antes de chamar a variável global **$_SESSION**. Outro ponto é que não existe necessidade de chamar 2 vezes essa função na mesma página php.

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['b']))
    {
        $_POST['email'] = $_SESSION['b'];
        echo $_SESSION['b']."<br/>1";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['b'] = "";
    }
    ...
```

A função **session_start()** Inicia uma nova sessão ou habilita uma já existente.

Mais info: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php

Mais info sobre a global $_SESSION: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php